# What kind of statistical analysis can be used in Lat/lng?

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-statistics

I am new to R programming and statistic. My boss assigned me a task to do some statistical analysis on the real estate using lat/lng points plus some variables like price. He want to me generate some graph of Hotspot but not heatmap. I have done some googling and know that Hotspot graph has something to do with statistical analysis, but I have never studied statistic before. can someone give me some directions of what method to use?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the **spatial statistics** world. R has some packages of point spatial statistics but the best is [spatstats](http://spatstat.github.io/).You can learn from the website or read the (Spatial Point Pattern:Methodology and applications with R written by Brian Ripley) 
Before using this package you should know fundamentals of descriptive and inferential statistics.
Learn **Spatial Autocorrelation** concepts beacause you want to analysis spatial pattern with values(ex:price).
Learn Nearest Neighbour concepts.You do not need deep Learn more about algorithms. Try to learn practically.